# Не запускается проект в android studio. Помогите

Tags: android, android-studio

На прошлой неделе скачал и запустила приложение в эмуляторе и на телефоне. Всё нормально работало. А теперь мигает красный кружочек внизу справа. Проект не запускается. Пробовал перестанавливать студио, не помогло[image: Если нажать на кружочек, вот такое окно]

Comment: это ошибка студии. проект должен собираться

Comment: при нажатии на зеленый треугольник ничего не происходит

Comment: запустила, пробовал ... кхм .. Маша, у вас раздвоение личности

Comment: сообщение говорит что у вас не настроен `adb` или просто не установлен или пути не указаны.